# Descargar binario desde BD al cliente con Laravel y MySql

Tags: php, laravel

Ya tengo como guardar los archivos en la base de datos (con un campo mediumblob) pero no tengo idea de como poder recuperarlos, estuve leyendo y por seguridad no se puede asignar valor a los input de tipo file, la idea es que el usuario suba un archivo por ejemplo txt (que se convierte a binario y se guarda correctamente) pero ahora tengo que hacer que se puedan descargar al PC del usuario, no pido código sino algo de orientación! Como podria hacer para que se descarguen tipo drive?

Comment: ¿Porque guardar archivos en la BD? No consideras que es mejor subir el archivo al servidor, después en tu tabla almacenas el nombre del archivo y para lectura o descarga solo necesitas ese nombre y otorgar la ruta hacia el archivo en el servidor.

Comment: Por seguridad, considero que es más dificill acceder a la base en lugar del servidor y si se perdiera esa carpeta todo se pierde, pero de todas formas ya lo solucioné, creé un archivo con lo que habia en la base y lo guarde en el servidor y de ahi lo descarga el usuario, despues lo elimino para que no quede en el servidor. Y se almacena encriptado en la base, mejor aun.

Comment: Por seguridad estoy de acuerdo y tu solución es buena, ¿usas Argon2i? con la última versión de Laravel y PHP podrías añadir más seguridad, saludos!

Comment: Estoy empezando con laravel no sabia de Argon2i, no es del todo seguro la forma en queda encriptado ya que quien conozca un poco laravel lo desencripta, uso el que trae por defecto, encrypt y decrypt, para passwords si es con bcrypt, y gracias por el consejo!